# Firebase: Update Item Timestamp on $save

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to work out how to update an `updatedAt` timestamp on my Firebase item.

The updated `thing.name` and `thing.description` are updated to the object, but I can't work out how to update the timestamp, even though I'm passing it in the `editedThing` object.

Here's my current code:

**HTML**

```
<h1>You are editing </h1>
<section class="unit">
  <form ng-submit="updateThing(selectedThing)">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="selectedThing.name" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="selectedThing.description" value="">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
var thingsRef = ref.child('things');
var things = $firebaseArray(thingsRef);
$scope.things = things;

// Add thing

$scope.addThing = function(thing) {
  var d = new Date();
  var newThing = {
    name: thing.name,
    description: thing.description,
    createdAt: d.toISOString(),
    updatedAt: d.toISOString()
  };

  things.$add(newThing);
};

// Update thing

var serviceId = $routeParams.serviceId;

if(serviceId) {
  $scope.selectedThing = getThing(serviceId);
}

function getThing(serviceId) {
  return $firebaseObject(ref.child('things').child(serviceId));
}

$scope.updateThing = function(thing) {
  var d = new Date();
  var editedThing = {
    name: thing.name,
    description: thing.description,
    updatedAt: d.toISOString()
  }

  $scope.selectedThing.$save(editedThing);
};
```

If I update the `name` or `description`, the values are updated in Firebase. But on update a new timestamp isn't generated and doesn't get pushed to Firebase.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since your `$scope.selectedThing` refers to a `$firebaseObject`, you can just modify it (`$scope.updatedAt = d.toISOString()`) and call `$save` on it. You probably should look into using `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` btw: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html

Comment: Are there any benefits to using a UNIX-based timestamp?

Comment: The important difference is not in the format, it's in reliability. If you have two clients and their clocks are completely out of sync, your client-generated timestamps will be an unreliable mechanism to for example order data by. When you use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` the timestamp will always be generated on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of the built-in [$extend](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html) functionality, you can add a timestamp during save without much fuss.

```
app.factory('SyncWithTimestamp', function($firebaseObject) {
   return $firebaseObject.$extend({
      toJSON: function() {
         return {
            name: this.name,
            description: this.description,
            createdAt: this.createdAt,
            // when data is returned to the server, set the updatedAt
            // to a new, server-generated timestamp (to avoid client discrepancies)
            updatedAt: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
         }
      }
   });
});
```

Now you need only use the extended factory normally:

```
app.controller(..., function(SyncWithTimestamp) {

   $scope.selectedThing = new SyncWithTimestamp(thingsRef.child(serviceId));

});
```

And the `updateThing()` method is redundant and probably going to create bugs. No need to copy data out of the synchronized object and then try to save it back into the synced object (which isn't done by passing args into `$save()` anyway). You can just use this:

```
<form ng-submit="selectedThing.$save()">
```

All of this, and a great deal more of the fundamentals of AngularFire are covered, with example snips, in [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html). It will save you some thrashing and pain to go through that in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the way $save() works, it doesnt take any parameters, you have to change de original $scope and then call $save().

you can try:

```
$scope.updateThing = function(thing) {
var d = new Date();
  $scope.selectedThing.name = thing.name;
  $scope.selectedThing.description = thing.description;
  $scope.selectedThing.date = d.toISOString()

  $scope.selectedThing.$save();
};
```

Comment: Can't seem to get that to work. Getting this error: `t.selectedService.$save is not a function`.

Comment: i edited the code, i think you can algo achieve this from the html `ng-submit="selectedThing.$save()"`